# Creating a one to many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to create a one (`Project`) to many (`ActionLog`) relationship between the following tables:

```
public class Projects {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } //I cut out most of the props as they were not relevant
   }

//They exist in two different .cs files. 

public class ActionLog {
     [Key]
     public int Id { get; set;}
     public string Information {get; set;}
     public ProjectsId {get; set;}
   }
```

Currently, in my viewmodel, I am doing a linq select for all entries that match my `ProjectTableId` and putting it into a list for each instance of `Project` .

I fear that this approach is extremely inefficient as it queries the database for every single entry of Projects. I know eager(?) loading would be best in this case, but I don't know how to implement it.

Tables can look like this: (Structure-wise)
[image]
* *Again the actual tables are necessarily complicated, so I cut out the unnecessary props for simplicity sake.*

Comment: Which approach are you using Database First, Code First ?

Comment: Codefirst. I am building these models first and then running a migration to throw them into my dbcontext as actual tables.

Comment: Well doing the classic `public List<ActionLog> actionlog {get; set;} ` is that problematic ?

Comment: @Bitz can you add the implementation of `OnModelCreating` method ?

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally, you'd have an `ICollection` of your many-related items:

```
public class Project
{
    ...

    public virtual ICollection<ActivityLog> ActivityLogs { get; set; }
}
```

With that, then, you can include the logs when querying the projects:

```
var projects = db.Projects.Include(m => m.ActivityLogs)
```

Comment: Trying to push this to the database causes the following validation issue:
`Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.ActivityLogs_dbo.Projects_ProjectId' on table 'ActivityLogs' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.`

I also used the list initializer as mentioned in CodeNotFound's solution.